# ValueError from Dataset.from_generator in Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm very new to TensorFlow and I am trying to procedurally load videos into a model with Dataset.from_generator that loads videos from file names inside of a generator. The issue I am having is this:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=0. Full shape received: []
```

And I have no idea what is causing it.

My code is as follows:

```
def video_gen():
    inputs = np.array([e.strip().split(" ")[0] for e in label_desc])
    labels = np.array([float(e.strip().split(" ")[1]) for e in label_desc])
    for elem in range(len(inputs)):
            yield (labels[elem], load_video(inputs[elem]))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    video_gen, 
    (tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None]))
)

model = models.Sequential()

# variable length, set height, set width, 3 channels
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(None, 240, 320, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For video input, use `tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed` which handles 5D input.

Consider a batch of 32 video samples, where each sample is a 128x128 RGB image with channels_last data format, across 10 timesteps. The batch input shape is `(32, 10, 128, 128, 3)`
**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
```

outputs.shape

```
TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```